# How set parameters for new windows in electron

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

I would like know how I can set configuration width and height in new window opened in electron above my code on main.js

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, webContents, session} = require('electron')
let mainWindow
function createWindow () {
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
width: 1000, height: 800,
webPreferences: {
  contextIsolation: false,
  nodeIntegration: true
}
})
mainWindow.loadFile('Control/index.html')
mainWindow.setMenu(null)
mainWindow.on('closed',  () => {
mainWindow = null
})
let wc = mainWindow.webContents 
 wc.on('new-window', (e, url) => {
     e.preventDefault()
     
     
 }
}
```